# Why the first code snippet can solve the stale closure and the second one can't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

It feels like there is nothing difference between the first one and the second one. But the first one code snippet can solve the stale closure. So, why the second one can't? I really can't figure it out. Can anyone explain it from the principle of JavaScript closures?

```
// ==========================  First code snippet ========================

let _formVal
export default function App() {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState('');

_formVal =  formVal

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('_formVal:', _formVal);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormVal(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={formVal}
      />
      <MemoziedSuperHeavyComponnent onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}

// ==========================  Second code snippet ========================

export default function App() {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState('');

const _formVal =  formVal
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('_formVal:', _formVal);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormVal(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={formVal}
      />
      <MemoziedSuperHeavyComponnent onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It does **not** solve the stale closure problem. It simply uses a global variable. Which will fail horribly one you render multiple instances of the component.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, there's only ever one `_formVal` variable created, which sits at the top module-scope level, so that's the variable your function component reads and updates.

In your second example, multiple `_formVal` variables are created for each render of your component, as each rerender calls your `App` function again, recreating the variables within your component, including the `_formVal` variable in a new scope context. Since the function reference returned by `useCallback()` never changes and is always the first function created on the initial render (due to the empty dependency `[]`), the function will always access to the first `_formVal` variable that was created in its surrounding scope and not the subsequent ones from future renders created in other scopes.

Small example with pure JavaScript:

```js
let memoizedHandleSubmit;

function foo(x) {
  let handleSubmit = function() {
    return x++;
  };
  
  memoizedHandleSubmit ??= handleSubmit; // if `memoizedHandleSubmit` doesn't have a value assigned to it yet, assign the value, otherwise leave it
  return memoizedHandleSubmit;
}

const bar = foo(1);
console.log(bar()); // 1
const bar2 = foo(10);
console.log(bar2()); // 2, not 10
```

Here we call the `foo` function multiple times, each time it is called, a new `x` variable, and `handleSubmit` function are created. The `memoizeHandleSubmit` function will essentially hold the first `handleSubmit` function that was created within the `foo` function by the first call to `foo`, subsequent calls to `foo` will reuse the previously created `handleSubmit` function (this is what your `useCallback` is doing). When the first `handleSubmit` function is created, the closure it saves is of the scope it's defined in, that means that the `handleSubmit` function has access to the variables defined outside of it, such as `x`. When the `foo` function is invoked again, a new scope is created with it's own value of `x` and a new `handleSubmit` function is created, but this one is discarded and not used, as instead, the old `handleSubmit` function is returned. The old `handleSubmit` function still only knows about the scope it was originally defined in as that's the closure it "saved", so it only knows about the `x` value from the original invocation, and so the log prints `2` instead of `10`.

---

Note that there are multiple ways to solve stale state issues, for this particular case, you most likely want to use `[formVal]` as your `useCallback()` dependency rather than `[]`, which will create a new reference to `handleSubmit` when `formVal` changes, allowing you to access the updated state value within it.

Answer (score 0):

In the two code snippets you provided, both seem quite similar at first glance, but they do have a subtle difference, which relates to how closures work in JavaScript. Let's break down the differences:

**First Code Snippet**:

```js
let _formVal;
export default function App() {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState('');

  _formVal = formVal;

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('_formVal:', _formVal);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormVal(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={formVal}
      />
      <MemoizedSuperHeavyComponent onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Second Code Snippet**:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState('');

  const _formVal = formVal;

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('_formVal:', _formVal);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormVal(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={formVal}
      />
      <MemoizedSuperHeavyComponent onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, let's focus on the key difference:

**First Code Snippet (with `let _formVal`)**:
In this snippet, `_formVal` is declared outside the `App` component. It is declared using `let` at the top of the module, making it a variable with module-level scope. This means it can be accessed and modified from anywhere within the module, including inside the `App` component. When you do `_formVal = formVal`, you are assigning the value of `formVal` from the component's state to `_formVal` in the module's scope. This creates a reference to the same variable.

**Second Code Snippet (with `const _formVal`)**:
In this snippet, `_formVal` is declared inside the `App` component using `const`. This means it is a local variable with block-level scope, specific to the `App` component's function. It is not accessible outside the component.

Now, let's discuss the implications of these differences in terms of closures:

In both cases, when the `handleSubmit` function is created using `useCallback`, it captures variables from its surrounding scope to form a closure. In the first code snippet, `_formVal` is a module-level variable, so it's accessible within the closure created by `useCallback`. In the second code snippet, `_formVal` is a local variable, so it's also accessible within the closure created by `useCallback`.

In terms of solving "stale closures," both code snippets should behave similarly because `_formVal` is captured by reference in both cases. When the `handleSubmit` function is executed, it will always log the current value of `_formVal`.

So, the reason why both snippets work similarly and can solve the "stale closure" problem is that `_formVal` is captured as a reference in both cases, ensuring that the correct and up-to-date value is used when the `handleSubmit` function is called. The difference in variable scope (module-level vs. block-level) doesn't affect the behavior in this context.